# nopCommerce 4.2: How to configure SSL related settings on nopCommerce to work https on Store Homepage

Tags: asp.net, ssl, configuration, nopcommerce

I have hosted my site on SmarterASP.NET. Everything was working good before I installed SSL. After installing SSL, the following scenario happened:

> ```
> Works => http://pourobazar.com
> Works => https://pourobazar.com/Admin
> Works => https://pourobazar.com/login
> Does not work => https://pourobazar.com
> ```

**System Specification:**

> ```
> nopCommerce Version: 4.2
> Hosting Server: Windows
> Hosting Provider: SmarterASP.NET
> SSL Installation: I got it free with my semi dedicated host plan
> ```

I set the following changes in database:

**Store table:**

> ```
> Name -> Nestapp
> Url -> https://www.pourobazar.com
> SslEnabled -> True
> Hosts -> pourobazar.com
> ```

**Setting table:**

> ```
> securitysettings.forcesslforallpages -> True
> ```

Would you please help me out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Rahi

Answer (score 2):

restart web site and check.
If not resolve remove settings for https and ssl and check for http. after set settings for https :

```
Url -> https://www.pourobazar.com
SslEnabled -> True
forcesslforallpages -> True
```